# Green button no longer maximizes iTunes window

Tags: macos, itunes, window

The typical green "maximize" button in iTunes doesn't function as expected. Instead of maximizing the window it toggles the mini-player function. I am looking for a way to return the original function of maximizing the window. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate Indrek's reply but I was looking for the default to be maximize and secondarily (forgot about modifier keys) to be the mini-player function.

As it turns out, the more permanent fix is quite simple. Evidently it is an accessibility function which can be dealt with through terminal and rewriting the default value for the "maximize button" function as follows:

```
defaults write com.apple.iTunes zoom-to-window -bool YES
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac, then hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button and press the green button. This will maximize the window.